# Navigation Drawer back button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I implemented Navigation Drawer in my app. It's just a sample app, auto-generated Navigation Drawer fragments and activities from Android studio. I'm starting an activity from a section list item like this:

```
public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.pocetna);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.oglasna_ploca);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.e_novine);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.portal);
            break;
        case 5:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.raspored);
            startActivity(new Intent(this, RasporedWebView.class));
            break;
    }
}
```

When I use the back button, could I get back to let's say case 1 or even MainActivity (closing navigation drawer), because when I call the activity, and go back it returns to a blank activitity (or w/e), and then I must click back button once more. I tried searching for solutions, but couldn't find any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried overriding `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: @KartikKaushik Could you post an example please, I'm a beginner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html).

Then add the below code to do Back button in Activity

```
ActionBar actionBar;
actionBar=getActionBar();

actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: 
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```